# Entity Framework 4.1 abstract class and discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Currently I have a problem that I can't understand.

I have 2 entities in my model

```
[Table("TX_REDEVABLE")]
public abstract class Redevable
{

}

[Table("TX_BILLET_STATION")]
public class BilletStation 
{
    [Column("BST_ID_INFO_RDV")]
    public Int64? RedevableId { get; set; }

    [UserVisible(Ordre = 23)]
    [Display(Name = "Redevable")]
    [ForeignKey("RedevableId")]
    public virtual Redevable Redevable { get; set; }
}
```

And I try to make a query like this:

```
var q = (from b in Repository.DataContext.BilletStation
         where b.Redevable != null
         select b).ToList();
```

It works fine it my class `Redevable` is abstract.
But now, I need to instanciante a new `Redevable` so I couldn't have an abstract class.

Without the abstract keyword, I now have an error
saying that `the "extend2"."discriminator" is undefined.`

Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
i created a new class called "RedevableConcrete" that inherits from "Redevable" and i marked it as NotMapped.

This way, i can instanciante it to create some new entities and my query works.